# How to correctly imbed matplotlib figures in different tkinter notebook tabs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

My GUI uses tkinter notebook with two tabs (call it *A tab*, *B tab*). Inside each tab, I have a frame container that holds various buttons. A user is to press a button to plot something. When another button is pressed, the plot should update with new data. I can get this to work properly for either *A tab* or *B tab*, but not both.

The problem is that when a new button is pressed (say when I am on *A tab*), the new data will be plotted on *figure_a*; however, the old data is not cleared. I can see the x-axis, and y-axis values of the previous plot. Please see the overall structure of my *plot_xy* function below.

Am I not using canvas.draw() in the correct places? The fact that I am passing figure and canvas as input to my plot_xy function, could this be causing the issue? Am I not correctly clearing older instances of figures or axes somewhere?

This problem goes away, if I comment out *block B* (see below). But if I did this, the user would obviously not be able to plot anything when they are on *B tab*. There seems to be some kind of interaction between the *figures* in *A tab* and *B tab*. Perhaps I am not understanding how matplotlib keeps track of different figures/canvases. Also, if I were to write block B before block A, the problem (old plot not clearing up before new plot is made) shifts from A tab to B tab.

You will notice that I have created two instances of *figure* via the same function: *self.figure_a = draw_figure()* and *self.figure_b = draw_figure()*. I get the same issue if I create my figures as *plt.figure(1)*, and *plt.figure(2)*.

Also notice that my *plot_xy* function has various *if, else* blocks that checks the data and decides whether to make a histogram plot, a scatter plot, or some other plot type. Right after each if statement, I have inserted *plt.clf()*, and within each if block (at the end), I have *canvas.draw()* and *toolbar.update()* calls.

The GUI is setup to call the plot_xy function by default during the GUI launch to generate a default plot.

```
import ...
from plot_file import plot_xy

class GUI():
def __init__(self, root):     
    self.nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
    self.nb.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    self.frameA = tk.Frame(self.nb)
    self.frameA.pack()
    self.frameB = tk.Frame(self.nb)
    self.frameB.pack()

    self.nb.add(self.frameA, text='tab A')
    self.nb.add(self.frameB, text='tab B')

    self.a_widgets = A_Widgets(self.frameA)
    self.b_widgets = B_Widgets(self.frameB)

    self.a_widgets.plot_button_a.configure(command=self.create_plot_a)
    self.b_widgets.plot_button_b.configure(command=self.create_plot_b)


    --------------Beginning of block A--------------------
    self.figure_a = self.draw_figure()
    self.canvas_a = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure_a, master=self.a_widgets.frame1)
    self.canvas_a.get_tk_widget().grid(....)

    self.toolbar_a = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas_a, self.a_widgets.frame1)
    self.toolbar_a.grid(...)
    --------------End of block A--------------------------



    --------------Beginning of block B--------------------
    self.figure_b = self.draw_figure()
    self.canvas_b = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure_b, master=self.b_widgets.frame1)
    self.canvas_b.get_tk_widget().grid(....)

    self.toolbar_b = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas_b, self.b_widgets.frame1)
    self.toolbar_b.grid(...)
    --------------End of block B--------------------------


    def draw_figure(self):
       figure = plt.figure()
       return figure
 
 .....
 
 def create_plot_a(self):
     ...
     ...
     plot_xy(self.canvas_a, self.figure_a, etc.)

 def create_plot_b(self):
     ...
     ...
     plot_xy(self.canvas_b, self.figure_b, etc.)

 ....
 ....
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     root = tk.Tk() 
     GUI(root)
     root.mainloop()
```

In a separate file, plot_file.py, I have my plotting function which takes canvas, figure as inputs along with data, etc.:

```
def plot_xy(canvas, figure, toolbar, data, ...):
    if ...:
        plt.clf()
        ax = figure.add_axes(...)
        ax.box_plot(data, ....)
        .
        .
        canvas.draw()
        toolbar.update()
  
    else..:
        plt.clf()
        ax = figure.add_axes(...)
        ..
        ax.scatter(data, ....)
        ..
        canvas.draw()
        toolbar.update()
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In the function plot_xy, instead of using plt.clf() which clears the current figure (which is not always the figure I wanted to clear based on my usage case), I used figure.clf(). Problem solved! figure.clf() explicitly clears the figure that is being referenced in the function.